# How to get the contents of a URL into a Django ImageField in a model?

Tags: python, django, model, download

Suppose I have the following model definition:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

Now further suppose I would like to take the contents of a remote URL and insert a row into the model above. Take this image for example:

https://www.python.org/images/python-logo.gif
[image]

I begin with the following code:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

fn = 'https://www.python.org/images/python-logo.gif'

# Read the contents into the temporary file.
f = NamedTemporaryFile()
f.name = fn
f.write(urlopen(fn).read())
f.flush()

# Create the row and save it.
r = Image(image=File(f))
r.save()
```

I see no reason why this shouldn't work. After a bit of debugging, I've discovered that:

- the remote image is downloaded without error and stored in the temporary file
- the file is created in the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory but has a size of 0
- the row is not saved and yet *no exception is thrown!*

Can anyone shed some light as to what's going on here? What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to do this?

I am running Django 1.4 on Linux if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there are no exceptions?  When I try this I get `AttributeError: Unable to determine the file's size.`  Which is probably caused by `f.name = fn`.  A file without an actual path (fn is an URL) can't be measured.  Restoring f.name to its original value fixes both of your issues.

If you want to explicitly set the name of the new file, use:

```
newfile = File(f,name='python-logo.gif')
r=Image(image=newfile)
r.save()
newfile.close()
```

(The extra lines because File objects don't close automatically)